# Wildfly 8.2.1 class loader issue

Tags: wildfly, classloader, wildfly-8

We have the following project structure in wildfly 8.2.1

```
C:.
└───Abc.ear
    ├───library
    ├───xyz.war
         └───WEB-INF
              ├───classes
              ├───lib
                   └───AccessControl.jar
                   └───acem.jar
```

We are getting the resource bundle using the following code.

```
rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle(bundleName, locale, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
```

Whereas we have the property file named xyz.properites in both the AccessControl.jar and acem.jar under the same com.test package. when we deploy this project in the Linux environment in some Linux environments it is getting the xyz.properties from the AcceccControl.jar file and in some other environments, it is getting picked from the acem.jar file.

My Question here is we would like to always read the properties file in the AccessControl.jar for the xyz.war application. How can we make sure that classloader order is maintained always?

Comment: You'd really need to have different names for the properties file. AFAIK there is no guarantee in which order items are loaded.